# working example of cfUserNotificationCreate

Tags: xcode, macos

Am looking for working example of cfusernotificationcreate()
or cfusernotificationNotify()

I tried few options and didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked out for me.

```
const void* keys[] =
{
    kCFUserNotificationAlertHeaderKey,
    kCFUserNotificationAlertMessageKey,
    kCFUserNotificationCheckBoxTitlesKey,
    kCFUserNotificationPopUpTitlesKey
};
CFTypeRef texKeys[3] = { CFSTR("1"), CFSTR("2"), CFSTR("3") };
CFArrayRef texVals = CFArrayCreate( NULL, texKeys, 3, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);

CFTypeRef paramKeys[4] = { CFSTR("1"), CFSTR("2"), CFSTR("3"), CFSTR("4") };
CFArrayRef paramVals = CFArrayCreate( NULL, paramKeys, 4, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);

const void* values[] =
{
    CFSTR("VBNIO"),
    CFSTR("parameters"),
    paramVals,
    texVals
};
CFDictionaryRef dict = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, sizeof(keys)/sizeof(*keys), &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

SInt32 err32 = 0;
CFUserNotificationRef notif = CFUserNotificationCreate(NULL, 0, kCFUserNotificationPlainAlertLevel, &err32, dict);

CFOptionFlags responseFlags = 0;
SInt32 response = CFUserNotificationReceiveResponse(notif, 120, &responseFlags);
CFRelease(dict);
```

Any idea how to fill in initial button values ?